# how to fix "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in python

Tags: python

i have been trying to print text and it is giving me the Error, as I try to fix it I cant find anything really useful to fix this. I don't know what I am doing wrong. can someone help. Here is my code:

```
sworddict={"playerlevel": 1, "playerxp": 0, "playerxpneeded": 100, "enemy": ("Goblin", "Gladiator", "Vampire", "Zombie", "Clone of Yourself"), "enemyhp": 50, "swordtype": ("Gladiator", "Katana", "Scimitar", "Rapier", "LongSword", "Broadsword", "Cutlass", "ShortSword"), "swordmodifier": ("Speed", "Power"), "swordmagic": ("Fire", "Ice", "Lightning", "Wind", "Dark", "Toxic"), "magicpower": 100, "swordlevel": 1, "swordxp": 0, "swordxpneeded": 100, "playerhp": 100}
    sworddict2={"chosenenemy": random.choice(sworddict["enemy"]), "chosensword": random.choice(sworddict["swordtype"]), "chosenmagic": random.choice(sworddict["swordmagic"]), "chosenmodifier": random.choice(sworddict["swordmodifier"])}


print("Here are your player stats\n")
print("\t\t\t\t______________\n")
print("\t\t\t\t|Player stats|\n")
print("Player HP left is: " + str(sworddict['playerhp']))
print("Player MPP left is: " + str(sworddict['magicpower']))
print("Player Level is: " + str(sworddict['playerlevel']))
print("Player XP amount is: " + str(sworddict['playerxp']) + "/" + str(sworddict['playerxpneeded']))
```

Comment: Can you share `sworddict`?

Comment: You can fix it by using integers as string indices. Or by using a dictionary instead of a string with non-integer indices.

Comment: Your `sworddict` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: i just edited in the dictionary

Comment: If I run the code exactly as you pasted it, I don't get an error.  Something is happening in the code you're actually running that changes `sworddict` into a string -- maybe you did `sworddict = str(sworddict)` at some point?

Comment: im using a server to run this. If you look it does have str() with them, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: i did edit the code a bit to make it easier to read. it is a discord bot and I'm using discord.py to make it. i do get the error even after deleting the str() in it. and no i don't have sworddict = str(sworddict) anywhere

Comment: also i only get the error when I am using the server. Otherwise if I just run it off my mac it works fine @Samwise

Comment: Search your code for all the places where you say `sworddict =`.  One of those statements is assigning a `str` value to it -- maybe it's not `str(sworddict)`, maybe it's something else entirely.  You could try printing out your `sworddict` value before it errors to see what string it is; that might make it easier to guess where the bug was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import random? Also make sure that the indentation is correct because after I fixed that it worked. Sworddict2 should be in line with the first line dictionary.

Comment: yes i did import random. the indentation is also correct as far as I can see

Comment: https://repl.it/join/lwclrgck-pravinrajah Is this what you were trying to get?